# I am not using any authentication method to login in Django. I am using this function is it right?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views

```
'''
def login_action(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
    else:
        user = Admin_user.objects.get(email_id=request.POST.get('email'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
        if user!=None:
            return HttpResponse("Loged IN")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not a User")
'''
```

this Method Works for me is it a right method. I don't use authenticate method because my models has 5 user type.  can any one suggest me a method for 5 user type if my method is not right. Is there any security issues using this method

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use Django's authentication system instead of trying to create your own. If you need different user types then you can create user profiles that link to the user model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

The `User.model` of Django provides a `groups` field.
[Groups -Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups) use this to declare certain User types/ groups. If you have additional Custom User Models i would recommend to use the `User.primary_key` in your custom other user models as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but to keep things secure and well organized, I used the normal Django build in authentication view.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='authentification/client_login.html',
                redirect_authenticated_user=True,next_page='client-home'), name='client-log-in'),]
```

And then I created a custom decorator to check if the user is allowed to enter the requested url.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from django.contrib.auth import  logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def authorization(view_func) :
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # import the urls for each user
        from CLIENT_A.urls import urlpatterns as client_a_urls
        from CLIENT_B.urls import urlpatterns as client_b_urls
        # check if the requested url exist in the client_a_urls
        if request.resolver_match.view_name in [client_a_urls[i].name for i in range(len(client_a_urls))]:
            # now we can check all the authorizations we want and take actions
            if not request.user.is_authenticated :
                messages.error(request, _('Pour accéder à cette page, vous devez d\'abord être connecté.'))
                return redirect(reverse('client-log-in'))
            if  request.user.is_superuser or request.user.is_client_b or not request.user.is_client_a:
                logout(request)
                messages.warning(request, _('Vous n\'êtes pas autorisé à accéder à cette page!'))
                return redirect(reverse('client-log-in'))
            # if user pass all the tests he's allowed to access the view
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       if request.resolver_match.view_name in [client_b_urls[i].name for i in range(len(client_b_urls))]:
           # we can do the same for client_b 
           pass
```

It's quite simple to utilize this decorator. :

```
from YourProject.decorators import authorization

@authorization
def Client_a_home(request):
    return render(request, 'application/dashboard/client_dashboard.html')
```